# How NSOperation handle network connection loss while downloading huge data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

In my app created NSOperationQueue of NSOperation to download multiple images in background.I wanted to know what will happen if network connection is lost while downloading data.Whether all those are operations which are still in queue are marked as finished and removed from queue or will remain in queue and again start downloading process when network is established again or something else?

Can anyone explain how NSOperationQueue works in such scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current NSOperation will continue with whatever logic is left when it receives the failure signal, and then terminate as normal, causing the NSOperationQueue to begin running the next NSOperation. If the internet still isn't back, it'll fail as well, and will just keep moving through the queue whether the network re-connects or not, failing all the connections unless the network reconnects.

There's probably quite a few different ways to handle this, because there's a lot to consider. For instance, you could put some logic in your code to mark an NSOperation as unsuccessful if it fails due to a network drop-out, and re-add failed NSOperations back into the queue. However, what if the network stays down for ages? Would your implementation be okay to keep trying to download images forever, or should you only let it re-try a particular file download a few times before giving up until the next time that feature is used?

You could also use a series of network reachability checks, such as before an NSOperation is added to the queue, before the NSOperation itself launches the NSURLConnection, etc. Should it fail you could have the NSOperation wait around until the network is re-connected and continue. (It's not ideal to do that, but because you're running it on a background thread it won't freeze the app's interface for the user at least).

If you wanted to, you could even implement the functionality you asked about in your question. That is, upon a network drop-out, cancelling all remaining operations in the NSOperationQueue, informing the user they'll have to re-try when the net comes back on. Then the next time the feature is called, re-add all those remaining NSOperations.

Comment: Thanks @Andeh for your answer, I think its better that NSOperation terminates normally when there is no network because according to my requirement it is again going to download images after particular time interval.